# Definition of class function

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC set theory, as usual let $\omega$ be the set of natural numbers and $V$ the universe, which is a proper class.

I want to define a "class function" $F : \omega \to V$ by $n \mapsto \omega + n$.

(Actually, the final aim is to show, using the axiom of replacement, that $$\{ \omega , \omega + 1 , \omega + 2 , \ldots \}= \{ \omega + n \, | \, n \in \omega \}$$ is a set, but with this latter part I have no problems, so I won't go into it.)

Intuitively I see how $\omega + n$, for any particular $n$, is defined: you just iterate with the successor function $s$ to obtain that $\omega + n$ is a set for each $n \in \omega$.

Now I was thinking about what the expression "$F : \omega \to V:n \mapsto \omega + n$" in ZFC means, i.e., which formula of the language of set theory corresponds to it.

I think it is the following.

"$F : \omega \to V : n \mapsto \omega + n$" is an abbreviation for the formula

"$F : \omega \to V$ is a function" $\wedge$ $[ \forall n \in \omega \, ( n , \omega + n ) \in F ]$.

Here "$F : \omega \to V$ is a function" is an abbreviation for

"$F$ is a function" $\wedge$ $\mbox{dom} ( F ) = \omega$ $\wedge$ $\mbox{range} (F) \subseteq V$,

where "$F$ is a function" and $\mbox{dom} (F) \subseteq \omega$ are of course itself again abbreviations (I won't give them here for reasons of brevity), and

$\mbox{range} ( F ) \subseteq V$ is an abbreviation for $\forall y \, ( \exists x \, (x,y) \in F \rightarrow y = y )$. (Which is a always true, so in retrospect I may as well had left this part out.)

So far so good, I guess.

But what about the expression $\forall n \in \omega \, ( n , \omega + n ) \in F$?

My 'problem' here is the $\omega + n$ in the formula. How can I express this? I've been thinking and searching for references about this for quite a while but I still haven't found a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Why not just $F = \{ ( x , y ) : x \in \omega \land y = \omega + x \}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the same definition of $F$ that I gave. But the point is: how to express $y = \omega + x$?

Comment: They're taken from a recursive definition.  You use transfinite recursion to define $+$ for ordinals.

Comment: Okay. Is there no way to avoid transfinite recursion for this? I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. What kind of axioms do we need for that?

Comment: Where is @AsafKaragila when one needs him?

Comment: @Elisheva You can use finite recursion, I suppose: $h(0) = \omega$ and $h(n+1) = \text{Suc}(h(n))$.  Or, you can define $+$ to be the unique order-isomorphism between $( \{ 0 \} \times \alpha ) \cup ( \{ 1 \} \times \beta )$ (viewed as a subset of ordered pairs of ordinals with respect to the lexicographic ordering) and the ordinals.

Comment: That's right, I think, recursion "on $n$" suffices. However, still, in the 'formalization' so far in class we haven't developed the machinery of even finite recursion. I guess it follows from the replacement axiom, also? We haven't defined 'ordinal' in class. Basically I want to do it as 'primitive' as possible.

Comment: @Andreas: Taking my rare "over six hours sleep".

Comment: Related, if not possibly duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305575/axiom-of-replacement

Comment: I have seen this; I did not understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "$\omega + n$" is defined recursively according to

- $\omega + 0 = \omega$;
- $\omega + ( n + 1 ) = ( \omega + n ) + 1\;( = ( \omega + n ) \cup \{ \omega + n \} )$.

As the (class) function $\alpha \mapsto \alpha + 1$ is definable, it follows that there will be a formula in the language of set-theory that corresponds to $n \mapsto \omega + n$.  This formula will not be at all simple, but basically says the following:

> $\langle n , \alpha \rangle \in F$ iff either $n = 0$ and $\alpha = \omega$, or $0 < n < \omega$ and there is a function $f : n \to V$ such that $f(0) = \omega$ and $f(i+1) = f(i) + 1$ for all $i < n-1$ and $\alpha = f ( n-1 ) + 1$.

Note that there are *a lot* of abbreviations used in the above.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think I get it.